# how to create pop up like google chrome exit full screen pop up

Tags: javascript, jquery

how can we open a dialog like below which hide automatically after some seconds

[image]

Comment: have u tired something? At least some googing?

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with jQuery (not must be it is helpful), and the JavaScript funcrtion setTimeout
Please see the example:

```js
var pop = $('<div>You have gone full screen&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<a>Exit full screen</a></div>');

$('a', pop).click(closePop)
setTimeout(closePop, 3000)

pop.css({
  padding: 10,
  border: '1px solid gray',
  borderRadius: 2,
  display: 'inline-block',
  align: 'center',
})
$('a', pop).css({
  textDecoration: 'underline',
  color: 'gray',
  cursor: 'pointer'
})

function closePop() {
  pop.slideUp()
}
$(document.body).append(pop)
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```